# How to use a SQL View to populate webform

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

Need to use a View from SQL Server to display detail record for data stored in two tables. Have spent a week trying to use Linq to SQL classes and for whatever reason that just won't work, every time I try I get the same error 3004 (see prior question from last week). 
Now I am trying to use the view in a connection string similar to what I used for a gridview control. However this is a formview that needs to have questionID passed from the page with GridView. Can this be done?

Very new to programming in asp.net/C#

Pageload event:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!this.IsPostBack)
        {
            string connectionString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CS1"].ConnectionString;
            string selectSQL = String.Format("Select * from V_Questions where Id ='{0}'");
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(selectSQL, con);
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();

            adapter.Fill(ds, "Question");

            Submit_Details.DataSource = ds;
            Submit_Details.DataBind();

        }
    }
```

Detail page:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Submit_Detail.aspx.cs" Inherits="cs1.Submit.Submit_Detail" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
   <asp:FormView ID="Submit_Details" runat="server" Datakeynames="QuestionID" RenderOuterTable="false">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div>
            QuestionID:
            <asp:Label ID="lbl_Question" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval.("QuestionID") %>'></asp:Label>
        </div>
        <br />
        <script type="text/javascript">
            CKEDITOR.replace('txt_Stem');
        </script>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:Image id="Image1" AlternateText="No Image" runat="server" Height="200px" ImageUrl='<%# "data:image/jpg;base64,"+ Convert.ToBase64String((byte[])Eval("ImageFile")) %>' />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Image id="Image2" AlternateText="No Image" runat="server" Height="200px" ImageUrl='<%# "data:image/jpg;base64,"+ Convert.ToBase64String((byte[])Eval("ImageFile2")) %>' />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:Image id="Image3" AlternateText="No Image" runat="server" Height="200px" ImageUrl='<%# "data:image/jpg;base64,"+ Convert.ToBase64String((byte[])Eval("ImageFile3")) %>' />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Image id="Image4" AlternateText="No Image" runat="server" Height="200px" ImageUrl='<%# "data:image/jpg;base64,"+ Convert.ToBase64String((byte[])Eval("ImageFile4")) %>' />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:table id="table1" runat="server" GridLines="Both" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderColor="Black">
            <asp:tablerow>
                <asp:tablecell>
                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lbl_author" font-bold="true" Text="Author:"  Width="125"></asp:Label> 
                </asp:tablecell>
                <asp:tablecell>
                    <asp:Label ID="txt_author" runat="server" Text='<%#Item.Author %>' ></asp:Label>
                </asp:tablecell>
            </asp:tablerow>
            <asp:tablerow>
                <asp:tablecell>
                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lbl_Stem" font-bold="true" Text="Stem:"  Width="125"></asp:Label> 
                </asp:tablecell>
                <asp:tablecell>
                    <asp:Label ID="txt_Stem" runat="server" Text='<%# Item.Stem %>'></asp:Label>
                </asp:tablecell>
            </asp:tablerow>
            <asp:tablerow>
                <asp:tablecell>
                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lbl_RespA" font-bold="true" Text="Response A:"  Width="125"></asp:Label> 
                </asp:tablecell>
                <asp:tablecell>
                    <asp:Label ID="txt_RespA" runat="server" Text='<%# Item.RespA %>' ></asp:Label>
                </asp:tablecell>
            </asp:tablerow>
            <asp:tablerow>
                <asp:tablecell>
                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lbl_RespB" Font-Bold="true" Text="Response B:" Width="125"></asp:Label>
                </asp:tablecell>
                <asp:tablecell>
                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="txt_RespB" Text='<%# Item.RespB %>' ></asp:Label>
                </asp:tablecell>
            </asp:tablerow>
            <asp:tablerow>
                <asp:tablecell>
                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="Lbl_RespC" Font-Bold="true" Text="Response C:" Width="125"></asp:Label>
                </asp:tablecell>
                <asp:tablecell>
                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="txt_RespC" Text='<%# Item.RespC %>' ></asp:Label>
                </asp:tablecell>
            </asp:tablerow>
            <asp:tablerow>
                <asp:tablecell>
                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lbl_RespD" Font-Bold="true" Text="Response D:" Width="125"></asp:Label>
                </asp:tablecell>
                <asp:tablecell>
                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="txt_RespD" Text='<%# Item.RespD %>' ></asp:Label>
                </asp:tablecell>
            </asp:tablerow>
            <asp:tablerow>
                <asp:tablecell>
                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lbl_RespE" Font-Bold="true" Text="Response E:" Width="125"></asp:Label>
                </asp:tablecell>
                <asp:tablecell>
                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="txt_RespE" Text='<%# Item.RespE %>' ></asp:Label>
                </asp:tablecell>
            </asp:tablerow>
            <asp:tablerow>
                <asp:tablecell>
                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lbl_Answer" Font-Bold="true" Text="Answer:" Width="125"></asp:Label>
                </asp:tablecell>
                <asp:tablecell>
                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="txt_Answer" Text='<%# Item.Answer %>' ></asp:Label>
                </asp:tablecell>
            </asp:tablerow>
            <asp:tablerow>
                <asp:tablecell>
                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lbl_Critique" Font-Bold="true" Text="Critique:" Width="125"></asp:Label>
                </asp:tablecell>
                <asp:tablecell>
                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="txt_Critique" Text='<%# Item.Critique %>' ></asp:Label>
                </asp:tablecell>
            </asp:tablerow>
            <asp:tablerow>
                <asp:tablecell>
                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lbl_KeyObjective" Font-Bold="true" Text="Key Objective:" Width="125"></asp:Label>
                </asp:tablecell>
                <asp:tablecell>
                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="txt_KeyObjective" Text='<%# Item.KeyObjective %>' ></asp:Label>
                </asp:tablecell>
            </asp:tablerow>
            <asp:tablerow>
                <asp:tablecell>
                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lbl_References" Font-Bold="true" Text="References:" Width="125"></asp:Label>
                </asp:tablecell>
                <asp:tablecell>
                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="txt_References" Text='<%# Item.References %>' ></asp:Label>
                </asp:tablecell>
            </asp:tablerow>
            <asp:tablerow>
                <asp:tablecell>
                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lbl_PracticeArea1" Font-Bold="true" Text="Primary Practice Area:" Width="175"></asp:Label>
                </asp:tablecell>
                <asp:tablecell>
                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="txt_PracticeArea1" Text='<%# Item.PracticeArea1 %>' ></asp:Label>
                </asp:tablecell>
            </asp:tablerow>
            <asp:tablerow>
                <asp:tablecell>
                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lbl_PracticeArea2" Font-Bold="true" Text="Secondary Practice Area:" Width="175"></asp:Label>
                </asp:tablecell>
                <asp:tablecell>
                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="txt_PracticeArea2" Text='<%# Item.PracticeArea2 %>' ></asp:Label>
                </asp:tablecell>
            </asp:tablerow>
            <asp:tablerow>
                <asp:tablecell>
                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblPracticeArea3" Font-Bold="true" Text="Tertiary Practice Area:" Width="165"></asp:Label>
                </asp:tablecell>
                <asp:tablecell>
                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="txt_PracticeArea3" Text='<%# Item.PracticeArea3 %>' ></asp:Label>
                </asp:tablecell>
            </asp:tablerow>
            <asp:tablerow>
                <asp:tablecell>
                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lbl_PracticeArea4" Font-Bold="true" Text="Additional Practice Area:" Width="180"></asp:Label>
                </asp:tablecell>
                <asp:tablecell>
                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="txt_PracticeArea4" Text='<%# Item.PracticeArea4 %>' ></asp:Label>
                </asp:tablecell>
            </asp:tablerow>

        </asp:table>

    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:FormView>
```

Form that is passing the query string for the new form. The top link is the one is question (for Submit_Detail).

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" Caption="Submitted Questions" AllowSorting="True" 
CaptionAlign="Left" EmptyDataText="You have not submitted any Questions." PageSize="5"
AutoGenerateColumns="false">
<Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="QuestionID" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("QuestionID") %>' />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="KeyObjective" HeaderText="Key Objective" ItemStyle-Width="150" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="SubmitDate" HeaderText="Submitted Date" ItemStyle-Width="50" />
    <asp:TemplateField>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="Details" runat="server" Text="View Details" PostBackUrl='<%# "~/Submit/Submit_Detail.aspx?Id=" + Eval("QuestionID")  %>'></asp:LinkButton>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="Clone" runat="server" Text="Create Clone" PostBackUrl='<%# "~/Submit/Submit_Clone.aspx?Id=" + Eval("QuestionID")  %>'></asp:LinkButton>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>

</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: I hate it that your having trouble with Entity Framework ... thats really the way to go but this can be done

Answer (score 0):

What you are wanting to use is a Query string

an example would be

www.yourwebsite.com?Param=100

http://www.dotnetperls.com/querystring

Comment: I have that done on the list form, and will add that to question,,, issue I am having is utilizing the query string on the new page, and getting the values from the sql query to bind to the items on the page.

Comment: so is the page load method above from the list form ?

Comment: Actually that was modified from what is working for the list form,,, trying to figure out how to do it for the details form. As mentioned, I'm a complete newb,,, and getting pretty frustrated at how hard it is to use a view from SQL... SQL I know just fine, asp.net/C# is being difficult!

Comment: so are you getting the data back from the view in your details form ?

Comment: No, it blows up on the first data element is should be using, which I have changed in trying to make this work to: <asp:Label ID="lbl_Question" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval.("QuestionID") %>'></asp:Label>

Comment: Whats the exception it gives when it blows up

Comment: First I get 16 errors for "Item" does not exist in the current context for all of the items in the form. One error for "Identifier expected", and that is the one returned when trying to run the form:  Compilation Error
Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.
Compiler Error Message: CS1001: Identifier expected
Source Error:
Line 7:                  <asp:Label ID="lbl_Question" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval.("QuestionID") %>'></asp:Label>

Comment: comment out your label for now and set a break point on your sql statement make sure your data looks like how you think it should look

Answer (score 0):

I think you might have several problems.  Not looking into the asp section yet, I think the first is you are not quite correctly using the SqlDataAdapter and not finishing the command text construction.

Try something like the following code replacing your first page load method example.  Notice comments symbol showing where several lines have changed.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string connectionString = ""; //preserve your connection string
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    string selectSQL = String.Format("SELECT * FROM V_QUESTIONS WHERE Id = @ID"); //
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(selectSQL, con);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int); //
    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    adapter.Fill(ds, "Question");

    Submit_Details.DataSource = ds;
    Submit_Details.DataBind();
}
```

Having added where necessary to your page load method, you will then also need to assign the necessary question id number to the value property of the `cmd.Parameters` as described in this documentation:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx

Do that before calling the `adapter.Fill(ds, "Question")`, making sure that your table name is also right.

Comment: Your comment on assigning value to the @ID parameter is what I was going to ask about,, as I don't see that being given a value. The value that needs to be assigned is the QuestionID being passed from the itemlist form in the postback url command: PostBackUrl='<%# "~/Submit/Submit_Detail.aspx?Id=" + Eval("QuestionID")  %>'>    I can't really see how to do that in the link you posted

Comment: Getting that request parameter would be done like 'string value = Request.QueryString["Id"];` documented here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.querystring(v=vs.110).aspx  The value returned will probably require null check and security sanitization before assigning it to the command parameter.

Comment: Tried a couple different versions,,, that look to make sense to me, but compiler does not like it. Says (1,13): error CS0103: The name 'cmd' does not exist in the current context
(1,43): error CS0103: The name 'Request' does not exist in the current context      Referencing the line added for setting parameter value:  cmd.Parameters["@ID"].Value = Request.QueryString["QuestionID"];

Comment: Sorry, I don't work asp.net so much ever/anymore.  I am not going to be able to help you much further with that.  Your expected Id parameter might also be in a form variable like 'string id = Request.Form["Id"];'.  Another tip, separating those value get/sets into different code lines makes it easier to debug.